# how do we combine matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have done the following command to generate 20 matrices with the same number of column and row.

```
alive <- vector(mode="list",length= 20)
mu <- 0.1
n <- 10
alive[[1]] <- 100
for(i in 2:20)
    alive[[i]] <- rbinom(10, alive[[i-1]], exp(-mu))

alive

[[1]]
[1] 100

[[2]]
 [1] 92 92 84 90 86 91 91 89 93 90

[[3]]
 [1] 85 78 75 81 79 79 83 82 87 84

[[4]]
 [1] 77 72 70 72 76 70 76 75 76 72

[[5]]
 [1] 71 61 62 64 73 64 69 68 68 62

[[6]]
 [1] 64 56 56 61 68 59 65 59 64 54

[[7]]
 [1] 58 50 53 55 63 52 60 49 53 48

[[8]]
 [1] 54 47 48 51 57 45 56 45 48 41

[[9]]
 [1] 46 40 43 43 52 40 52 42 47 37

[[10]]
 [1] 39 40 42 41 46 35 43 38 45 33

[[11]]
 [1] 34 38 39 39 45 32 42 36 44 29

[[12]]
 [1] 32 37 38 33 39 27 34 35 42 25

[[13]]
 [1] 28 37 33 29 35 25 32 35 38 23

[[14]]
 [1] 26 34 29 28 32 21 27 33 35 19

[[15]]
 [1] 22 32 28 25 31 21 18 33 33 15

[[16]]
 [1] 20 30 24 21 29 19 16 29 29 11

[[17]]
 [1] 19 29 22 20 26 18 12 27 27 10

[[18]]
 [1] 19 23 20 19 23 13 11 25 25  8

[[19]]
 [1] 19 22 16 18 21 11 11 25 23  7

[[20]]
 [1] 18 21 13 17 19  8  9 24 22  5
```

And now, how do i combine all of the matrices to a single matrix?

I tried to use this command :-

```
A = matrix (cbind(alive[[i]]), nrow=10, ncol=20, byrow = TRUE)        
A
```

However, it turns out to combine only the last matrix.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Many thanks!

Comment: `do.call(cbind,alive)`

Comment: thanks! u have been very helpful =)